# AWS S3 (with SDK 2.x) - File Upload to S3 Options (Less Memory consumption and without temp file) available?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, inputstream, fileinputstream

Recently we have decided to migrate the Java file upload/download use cases to be catered through AWS S3 from our old SFTP VM. My file sizes are usually between 0-10 MB's, and there can be multiple concurrent users (Java API) uploading the files.

While doing that, I came across 4 options majorly to upload the file to S3 bucket.

- **OPTION_1** : Inputstream to byteArray

`RequestBody.fromBytes(IoUtils.toByteArray(s3FileObject.getInputStream()));` /// This Consumes lot of memory as it reads the entire stream in to byteArray and then write to S3 through putObject

- **OPTION_2** : As InputStream

`RequestBody.fromInputStream(s3FileObject.getInputStream(), s3FileObject.getInputStream().available());` /// Here i reaaly do not have the Size of the inputStream (as s3FileObject.getInputStream().available() does not always be right to get length of input stream)

- **OPTION_3** : InputSream to File

`RequestBody.fromFile(file)` /// I really do not want to create the temp file on my Java serevr or temp folder as it is overhead vs our initial approach of uploading to VM through SFTP.

- **OPTION_4** : Multipart uplaod

`s3.uploadPart(part,RequestBody.fromBytes(bytes)).eTag();` // Minimum part size is 5 MB, so multiple users say 100 uploading those files can consume lot of Memory.

**How I was implementing earlier**
We had Apach VFS which used to open the outputstream to SFTP file, and we used to read small chunks from the inputStream and write to OutputStream (which is of the file in SFTP)

**Sample Code**

```
public long transferStream(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    long streamSize = 0;
    byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024];
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1)
    {
        streamSize += bytesRead;
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    return streamSize;
}
```

- **I have 2 Questions here**

1. Is there way to get the outputstream of S3 file and write with small chunks as above way ?
2. For the application with 4 GB machine and 2 GB XMX - how does the temp file option (OPTION_3 above) will work even after we delete the files after the uplaod.

Is there any better way of handing the S3 upload without too much of Memory Overhead and Temporary file.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also - this question is huge, can you break it down and make it more focused please?

Comment: Yes did that now, have some context hence it looks lengthy but it is required.